# What do the letters mean on this LiPo (or Li Ion) battery?

Tags: batteries, data, code

I’m trying to find a replacement battery for my Bluetooth earphone as they drain out very fast. It is a 3.7 V 55 mAh.

Looking through the options I see batteries with better capacity but the letters are different (the battery I have says AUN others have written PZY TX DX, etc.) what do these letters mean, and do I need to care about these?

[image: Here is the image of the battery]

Comment: You do not need to care. As long as the chemistry and cell count is the same, and the mAh and form factor is acceptable you are fine. 3.7V nominal means 1 cell Lithium Polymer. Not any other kind of lithium

Comment: @DKNguyen Welcome to the electrical engineering stack exchange! Unfortunately you have written your answer in the _comment_ section, an easy mistake for new users. Please familiarize yourself with the [tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help) section to learn how this website works.

Comment: @pipe While posting answers as comments is not ideal, sometimes users will post helpful information that could be perceived as an answer. I do this myself sometimes because I don't have time to write a more verbose or fully-sourced answer. Also, DK has been here for four years; hardly a new user.

Comment: /r/woooosh comes to mind.

Comment: @Velvel Are you suggesting Pipe's post is a joke and I didn't get it? Pipe's been here even longer, but I fail to see how writing such a comment is meant to be funny.

Comment: @JYelton I sincerely believe pipe's comment was meant as a joke. Maybe I'm mistaken... but that is exactly my kind of humor. It made me chuckle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some are probably date and lot codes. And maybe a hint as to the manufacturer or model.

It's really impossible to tell for sure without a specification (or a datasheet, but they are more rare in this space) **from the manufacturer themselves**. There isn't a standardized series or anything like that. And manufacturers may not choose to display their specifications in public, more like confidential info for their huge-quantity OEM buyers.

Aside from the voltage and rough mAh claim, you should probably concern yourself mainly with the physical size, whether the battery incorporates protection (and what kind) and maybe the connector and lead lengths.

If the supplier is on the dodgy side (and for replacement LiPo batteries they often are) the capacity (and other) claims may be exaggerated (or wildly exaugurated) so do your due diligence.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to care. As long as the chemistry and cell count is the same, and the mAh and form factor is acceptable you are fine. 3.7V nominal means 1 cell Lithium Polymer. Not any other kind of lithium

Comment: Thank you for the answer!